# Redux-React : How to pass the updated state to function onChange?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, redux, react-redux

I am new to React and was trying a simple thing. I do not understand how to modify the state and pass it to the function. Please find my code below : 
I am skipping the redundant code, only passing the point of focus, everything works fine except this functionality.

```
 state = {
    card: this.props.card // No probelm here , the props are correctly received in my component 
  };
```

I am trying update the state onChange and use this state value in my dispatcher to generate a new state after this event. Please find the code snippet of this functionality here :

```
<select
          class="form-control m-1"
          value={this.state.card.type}
          onChange={e => {
            let newType = e.target.value;
            this.setState(prevState => ({
              card: {
                ...prevState.card,
                type: newType
              }
            }));
            console.log(this.state.card) // **This gives me the old state, not updated one**
            this.props.updateCard(this.state.card) // Correctly receiving the updateCard Props , 
          }}
        >
          <option value="ABC">Option1</option>
          <option value="DEF">Option2</option>
        </select>
```

My Dispatcher :

```
updateCard: card=> {
    dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_CARD", card: card})}
```

My Reducer :

```
  case "UPDATE_CARD": {
      console.log("INSIDE REDUCER");
      console.log(action.card);
      return {
        cards: state.cards.map(card=>
          card.id === action.card.id ? action.card: card
        )
      };
    }
```

Please help on this. I did search a lot of stuff here but nothing was helpful.

Comment: In your code, your updating the state and passing to dispatch in same function, everything is in same scope so why can't you pass the new value directly to that dispatch itself ?

Comment: Thanks @RajKumar but can you please help me pass the modified state

Comment: Whenever you update the state, it will render the component to return the updated value to utilize it, here the problem is your trying to get the updated state inside the onChange event trigger, so that's the reason, your not getting the updated value

Comment: My apologies , when you say : pass the new value directly to the dispacth ,that's what i am doing . My new value is the modified state. 
What do you suggest ?

Comment: New Value which i mentioned is the value your passing to setSate. you can try like this.
`this.setState(prevState => {
              const updatedState = {
                card: {
                  ...prevState.card,
                  type: newType
                }
              };
              this.props.updateCard(updatedState);
              return updatedState;
            });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `setState` is not synchronous:

```js
...
onChange ={e => {
  let newType = e.target.value;
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    card: {
      ...prevState.card,
      type: newType
    }
  }), () => {
    console.log(this.state.card) // will give you the new value
    // you should also do any updates to redux state here to trigger
    // re-renders in the correct sequence and prevent race conditions
  });
  console.log(this.state.card) // **This gives me the old state, not updated one**
  this.props.updateCard(this.state.card) // Correctly receiving the updateCard Props ,
}}
...
```

Comment: Thanks , This works. If you dont mind can you please elaborate more on this ? Will be helpful in learning

Comment: Simply put `setState` is an asynchronous function which means the code does not stop execution and wait for it to complete before executing your console.log statement thus you are not guaranteed that it has completed by the time you log out the state in sequence this like. So read up on asynchronous javascript to avoid pitfalls like this in future :)

Comment: Thank you ! I just started JS last month and its been a bumpy ride :))

Comment: Haha yeah well, buckle up...;)